# What is the best option to convert library projects when using them in both .NET Core & .NET Framework Applications?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have applications in .NET 4.5.2 (Web Application, Web API, Windows Services & Windows Form). All these applications are sharing library project (Database Layer using ADO.NET). We are now going to convert the applications to .NET Core one by one and has started Web Application. I've ported my library project to .NETStandard 2.1 and now it is compatible with Web Application (.NET Core).

We have decided that we will not convert Windows Service & Windwos Form application to .NET Core but we must have to convert the Database Layer to a new project with new technology like Entity Framework Core. This database layer is going to be used by .NET Core & .NET applications. So my question is how should I create new project for database layer which can be used in both .NET Core & .NET applications as is?

There are few options but I'm confuse selecting one of them like (.NET Standard, .NET Core or .NET 4.8) Please help me choosing one that suites best in my scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: There's only one option. You have to target .NET Standard 2.0 until you move everything to .NET (Core) 5. .NET Standard 2.1 is only usable by .NET Core 3 projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one option - targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and upgrading executable projects to .NET 4.7.2 at least.

**Why**

.NET 4.8 is still .NET Old, and mixing .NET Core with .NET Old assemblies is only a stop-gap measure that easily leads to trouble. .NET Standard 2.1 is only usable by .NET Core 3.1 and later, so it's not an option either. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5, so unless you migrate everything to it, it's not an option either.

.NET 4.7.2 is required because it's the only version that supports .NET Standard 2.0 natively. Using .NET Standard 2.0 in earlier versions results in dependency hell and even MS advises against it. Almost *all* NuGet packages target NS 2.0 now, so moving to 4.7.2 is unavoidable, unless you want to use older libraries with bugs that were solved in later versions. .NET Framework 4.5.2 is simply too old

Not to mention the TLS situation - 4.5.2 doesn't use TLS1.2 by default, which means you already need to use workarounds to use HTTPS to call services, and won't be able to use TLS1.3 even if both the client and server OS support it. No HTTPS means no HTTP/2 too.

**Gradual migration**

Instead of migrating every module in the application though, you can introduce .NET Core technologies gradually. All Microsoft Extension libraries like Dependency Injection, Configuration, Logging, are .NET Standard 2.0 libraries, which means you can use them in .NET Old applications as well.

You could start by introducing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and Configuration to the existing .NET Framework applications.

- Instead of using a global logger, you can inject an ILogger instance to any class that needs logging, eg through a constructor parameter.
- You can replace any references to ConfigurationManager or `Properties.Settings.Default` with injected configuration objects. That's a good design anyway, removing any dependency to specific configuration technologies.

DI can also be added easily - your `Main` method will have to configure the Generic Host just like .NET Core applications do, and forms will have to accept dependencies in their constructors. [This article](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/dependency-injection-net-core-windows-form-generic-hostbuilder/) shows how to do this, but the actual code is simple:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
             .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
             {
                 services.AddSingleton<Form1>();
                 services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
                 services.AddScoped<IBusinessLayer, BusinessLayer>();
                 services.AddScoped<IDataAccessLayer, DataAccessLayer>(); 
 
             });
    var host = builder.Build();
             . 
    using (var scope=host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var form1 = scope.GetRequiredService<Form1>();
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
}
```

If `Form1` uses dependency injection

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    private readonly IBusinessLayer _business;
    public Form1(ILogger<Form1> logger, IBusinessLayer business)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _business = business;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
...
}
```

The logger and business layer instances will be created and passed to it when `GetRequiredService<Form1>()` is called.

Comment: Thanks, @Panagiotis Kanavos for this response also good idea about ConfigurationManager. You are star!!!

Answer (score 0):

Only netstd can be used in both netfx and netcore projects.
So any shared libraries will simply have to be netstandard.

Another idea - although arguably a bad one as Panagiotis Kanavos points out - is to use a service architecture instead. You could design your database in netfx or netcore, run it as a windows service and communicate via named pipes or TCP with the process from any other application(s). This way you can leave your database at netfx and convert your applications to netcore one by one - I think you get the jist.

Comment: `Another option is to use a microservice architecture instead.` that's not an option at all. They are services, with latencies 100K times greater than an in-memory call. The `micro` prefix is just branding. They are still services, hosted on a separate application, called over the network (even if that's optimized on the local machine). Going from a desktop application to a multi-layer architecture is a big change with completely different performance and design requirements. Instead of multiple small calls, the application now has to make fewer, bigger calls to avoid overhead

Comment: Or rather, it's an option the same way that switching a Smart for a pickup truck is an option. For driving through London. You do it only if you really have to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your thoughts.  I agree and i was more trying to lay out all the options i know - i've change the beginning of the text to hopefully reflect that better.